# The rotation of the rectangle relative to the rotated rectangle using C#

Tags: c#, rotation, geometry

**I have two rectangle:**

first `parent` rotated -15 degrees relative to the center of the canvas

next `children` rotated -15 degrees relative to the center of the canvas and rotated 5 degrees relative to the center of `parent`.

**Taking the original image:**
[image]

**Made the described modifications in the image editor:**
[image]

**It is necessary to repeat these operations with rectangles**, here is my code:

```
var parentAngle = -15;
var childrenAngle = 5;

var parent = new Rectangle(new Point(50, 160), new Size(200, 300));
var children = new Rectangle(new Point(25, 175), new Size(50, 50));

// load transformed file to as canvas
var bmp = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Temp\transform.png");

var size = bmp.Size;

var canvasCenter = new PointF(size.Width / 2, size.Height / 2);
var parentCenter = new PointF(parent.Location.X + parent.Width / 2, parent.Location.Y + parent.Height / 2);
var parentLocation = parent.Location;

var parentVertices = parent.GetVertices();
var childrenVertices = children.GetVertices();

// rotate by canvas center
var rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
rotateMatrix.RotateAt(parentAngle, canvasCenter);
rotateMatrix.TransformPoints(parentVertices);

// rotate children vertices
var rotateMatrix2 = new Matrix();
rotateMatrix2.RotateAt(childrenAngle, parentCenter);
rotateMatrix2.TransformPoints(childrenVertices);

 // translate vertices
var translateMatrix = new Matrix();
translateMatrix.Translate(parentLocation.X, parentLocation.Y);
translateMatrix.TransformPoints(childrenVertices);

// rotate by canvas center
rotateMatrix.TransformPoints(childrenVertices);


using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    g.DrawPolygon(Pens.Green, parentVertices);
    g.DrawPolygon(Pens.Blue, childrenVertices);
}
```

**Result**:
[image]

I was mistaken somewhere and parent matches but children don't  match. Maybe everything breaks down at the calculate parent offset?

**Update**:
The GetVertices function is implemented as a helper and looks like this:

```
    public static PointF[] GetVertices(this Rectangle rect)
    {
        return new[] {
            rect.Location,
            new PointF(rect.Right, rect.Top),
            new PointF(rect.Right, rect.Bottom),
            new PointF(rect.Left, rect.Bottom)
        };
    }
```

Comment: Translation is used when the rotation matrix is "pure", which means it transforms only rotating around the origin `(0,0)`. But your code `rotateMatrix.RotateAt(angle, center)` suggests it takes care of the required *translation-to-center -> rotate -> translate back* sequence when the center of rotation is not the origin.

Comment: @Ripi2, Thanks! It turns out that paint.net rotate selected layer relative to the center of the canvas. Because of this into the test case crept mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a few problems:

**First** - paint.net rotate selected layer relative to the center of the canvas. Therefore, nothing came together and had to redraw the test case
[image]

**Next** - I had to redo the calculation of transferring the location of the child to the top.
Now it looks like this:

```
var parentAngle = -15;
var childrenAngle = 5;

var parent = new Rectangle(new Point(50, 160), new Size(200, 300));
var children = new Rectangle(new Point(25, 175), new Size(50, 50));

// load transformed file to as canvas
var bmp = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Temp\rotate_5.png");

var size = bmp.Size;

var canvasCenter = new PointF(size.Width / 2, size.Height / 2);
var parentLocation = parent.Location;
var parentCenter = new PointF(parentLocation.X + parent.Width / 2, parentLocation.Y + parent.Height / 2);
var childrenLocation = children.Location;

// translate location children by parent location
children.Location = childrenLocation = new Point(parentLocation.X + childrenLocation.X, childrenLocation.Y + parentLocation.Y);
var childrenCenter = new PointF(childrenLocation.X + children.Width / 2, childrenLocation.Y + children.Height / 2);

var parentVertices = parent.GetVertices();
var childrenVertices = children.GetVertices();

//rotate by canvas center
var rotateChildrenMatrix = new Matrix();
rotateChildrenMatrix.RotateAt(childrenAngle, parentCenter);
rotateChildrenMatrix.TransformPoints(childrenVertices);

// rotate by canvas center
var rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
rotateMatrix.RotateAt(parentAngle, canvasCenter);

rotateMatrix.TransformPoints(parentVertices);
rotateMatrix.TransformPoints(childrenVertices);

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    g.DrawPolygon(Pens.Green, parentVertices);
    g.DrawPolygon(Pens.Blue, childrenVertices);
}
```

**Result**:
[image]